# Android app for newspaper

Tags: android

Since I'm newbie in android, I just wanna ask a noobish query of mine. Thanks for the help

I'm making an app of newspaper. So, my problem is that it will contain all news in one page, with a brief info of every news﻿ on that page. How can I do this? I mean when I scroll down the page, there should be different news with a heading and the brief info of that news.
(Look for a newspaper app for proper understanding of my question. Thankyou!!)

I apologize for my incorrect english & if I'm not able to explain the question properly.
Thanks

Comment: Add all the headline in list view and implement onitemclick listener of each item with scrollable

Comment: Well thanks for your reply..
Please correct me if I'm wrong. Adding all the headlines manually isn't a best practise, I guess. Instead I should store all the news in the DB with the headlines and then fetch it from there. Isnt it?

Comment: ya something like store in db and fetch fro m db strored in arraylist and set on adapter and set the adapter with listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can have a multi line ListView 1s line put the heading and second line put the brief info, When an item in the list view is clicked launch an activity which displays full news on closing the activity you will again see the menu ie List view

Comment: Just to be sure, I wanna ask you should I store news into the DB then fetch it or should I manually add it into the palette, ie mymenu.xml?

Comment: Store the news details in a db with headlines summary and full news retrieve the whole record and 1st 2 columns goes to the list view and on click launch activity contains the full news